# Is it possible to append a unique CSS class to multiple <li> elements, or re-sort them using Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, squarespace

Currently working on the Squarespace.com platform and I'd like to re-sort a dynamic Blog Category index that defaults to alphabetical sorting. This is how Squarespace generates the code:

```
<div id="moduleContentWrapper11663355" class="widget-wrapper widget-type-journalarchive">
    <div id="moduleContent11663355">
        <ul class="archive-item-list-pt">
            <li>
            <a href="/blog/category/category-one">Category One</a>
            <span class="entry-count">(1)</span>
            </li>
            <li>
            <a href="/blog/category/category-two">Category Two</a>
            <span class="entry-count">(1)</span>
            </li>
            <li>
            <a href="/blog/category/category-three">Category Three</a>
            <span class="entry-count">(1)</span>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Is it possible to re-sort the entries using Jquery, or worse case, can I append a unique CSS class to each `<li>` so I can manipulate each one using CSS?

Thanks!

Comment: fyi - your markup is invalid.

Comment: Ack! Thank you, I manually did the <li> portion, sorry! Fixed!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var i = 1;
$('.archive-item-list-pt li').each(function(item) {
   $(item).addClass('myClass'+i);
});
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't mention that each class must be different (match the blog category). I tried addClass and it worked perfect for appending a single class to all of the <li>s, but I need a different class for each so I can use CSS to selectively hide them.

Comment: This worked perfectly, but now I'm really going to be a pain in the ass... is it possible to append a unique identifier, according to the name of the category? For instance... the class=category-one  ? The reason I need that is because if I append a number to each class, then style via CSS, then we add a new category, the number will change and any styling I did previously won't match. If I use a unique class according to each category name, the styling of CSS would never change. Thanks again for your help here.

Answer (score 4):

the dom is really nothing but a complicated collection... you can use jquery to sort the li like an array.

```
var mylist = $('#moduleContent11663355 > ul');
var listitems = mylist.children('li').get();
listitems.sort(function(a, b) {
   var compA = $(a).text().toUpperCase();
   var compB = $(b).text().toUpperCase();
   return (compA < compB) ? -1 : (compA > compB) ? 1 : 0;
})
$.each(listitems, function(idx, itm) { mylist.append(itm); });
```

thanks to http://www.onemoretake.com/2009/02/25/sorting-elements-with-jquery/

Answer (score 2):

```
$('.archive-item-list-pt li').each(function(i,j) {
   $(this).addClass('yourClass'+i);
});
```

here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/h2gfT/7/

**update**

```
$('.archive-item-list-pt li').each(function(i,j) {
   var cls=$(this).children("a").text().toLowerCase();
    var idx = cls.replace(' ','-');

    $(this).addClass(idx);
});
```

**here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/h2gfT/9/**

one with jquery chaining hotness

```
$('.archive-item-list-pt li').each(function(i,j) {
   var cls=$(this).children("a").text().toLowerCase().replace(' ','-');  
   $(this).addClass(cls);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/h2gfT/11/

Comment: This worked great as well. The problem is the class will change if the number of categories on the page change. This would wipe out any styling that I do. Is it possible to append a unique identifier, according to the name of the category? For instance...  class=category-one (because that's the category name and URL) ? Thanks for your help here.

Answer (score 0):

Sort items in place based in the arbitrary key function

http://blog.mirotin.net/125/jquery-sortitems

Answer (score -1):

Sorting the entries with jQuery can be done in a couple diffrent ways, but if you just want to append CSS to each of them you could do that in two different ways.

```
$('li').each(function(l) { $(this).attr('class', '<insertnameofcssclasshere>') })
```

or

```
$('li').each(function(l) { $(this).css(<insertcssstuff here>) })
```

Of course, these would apply it to all li elements on your page. You would want to use more specific or contained selectors if you want to affect just some of them.